# Как обрезать fixed элемент внутри другого контейнера?

Tags: html, css

Существует блок, с `overflow: hidden`. Внутри которого обязательно должен быть элемент с `position: fixed`, т.к. нужно что бы он прилипал к "окну" страницы, но в тоже время не выходил за рамки родителя. Как это возможно сделать?

[Пример](https://codepen.io/predaytor/pen/gEeXvm): сейчас стоит `absolute`, потому изображение не выходит за рамки, и не может растянуться. Нужно что бы оно растягивалось на всю страницу.
`Background-position` не то, изображение как пример, здесь может быть что-угодно.

Спасибо.

**UPDATE**: `clip-path: inset(0)` родителю работает отлично!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0);
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: 'к "окну" страницы' значит к правой стороне страницы?

Comment: @nosferatu-id Нет, нужен left: 0, right: 0, top: 0. Просто что бы не вылазил за родителя.

Comment: а `display: flex` ?

Comment: @nosferatu-id он только "центрирует" контент, мне нужно совсем другое.

Comment: @Predaytor Объясни нормально, конкретнее. Приложи скриншоты, код нормальный вставь. Я тебя не понял, что нужно сделать? Сделать изображение на весь экран? Конкретнее опиши.

Comment: @Predayto или по container растянуть? гадать приходиться. непонятно. Если есть пример то чего хочешь, тоже тащи.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev код по ссылке доступен. Допустим контейнер 300х400, находится справа. Мне нужно вставить в него что-то (изображение например), которое должно вести себя как фиксированное, прилипать к сторонам страницы, но видимой частью должна быть только та что в контейнере.

Comment: @Predayto прямо мастерски объяснил. Ок вот у тебя есть контейнер уже в коде. И есть изображение. Тебе нужно чтобы это изображение вписалось по краям контейнера? Независимо от пропорций изображения? Так?

Comment: @Predayto я тебя понял отчасти. Картинка должна быть на весь экран, но видна лишь та часть, которая в контейнере 500на250 к примеру. Так? Если да, то, возможно нужна другая конструкция для твоей страницы. Опиши цель, какая страница в итоге должна получиться по замыслу - полностью, всё что на ней должно быть и как она работает.

Comment: @nosferatu-id Если я правильно понял, то решение сделанное мной, подойдёт. См сами.

Comment: @Predaytor бордер не работает.

Comment: @Predaytor оверфло в таком случае - не нужен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обрезать элемент с `position:fixed` родителем не получится. Но вы можете обрезать этот элемент с помощью `clip-path`.

Comment: Не подскажите как это сделать? Не могу понять.

Comment: пожалуйста, дополните ваш ответ примером использования этого свойства

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/347218)

Comment: @mymedia, вроде является.

Comment: @Инквизитор пример можете показать с картинкой? Ссылку на ресурс например.

Comment: @mymedia Я предложил иное решение. 2 варианта. Если интересно, то смотрите.

Comment: Большое спасибо. clip-path: inset(0) родителю помогло)

Answer (score 1):

Если просто обрезать, есть ещё такой метод: clip-path. См этот пример. 
Позицию какую надо укажешь сам.

У каждого метода есть как плюсы, так и минусы. ИМХО лучший метод, то что я прислал ранее Адаптивный, приближенный к твоему изображению. Он красивее, эстетичнее, и соблюдает геометрию, необычный.
В остальном - ты плохо объясняешь. Наплевательски.

```css
.inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  clip: rect(400px, 1300px, 650px, 800px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Так тебе надо?

Comment: Не совсем. Вот пример, то что вне бордера - должно быть скрыто, но изображение (может быть любой блок) растянуто по краям страницы. Я пробывал играть с z-index, но ничего хорошего не вышло. Я делал подобное с фиксированным хедером, там подойдет absolute, здесь же никак.

Comment: Добавил изображение.

Comment: @Predaytor Смотри

Comment: @Predaytor добавил второй вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал тебе вот такое решение. Держи!

```css
.m {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
m. img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* background: yellow; */
    /* opacity: 0; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.it {
width: 100%;
height: 410px;
background: blue;
}
.il {
width: calc(54% - (500px / 2));
background: yellow;
}
.i {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: transparent;
border: 12px solid rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.72);
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ir {
width: calc(46% - (500px / 2));
background: yellow;
}
.ib {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #03A9F4;
}
.ib, .il, .ir, .it {
    background: rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.63);
}
```

```html
<div class="m">
<img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="" >
<div class="c">
<div class="it"></div>
<div class="il"></div><div class="i"></div><div class="ir"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Надеюсь не нужно пояснять как пользоваться.

Comment: С расчетами под себя в процентах или фиксированные - думаю разберёшься самостоятельно.

Comment: Есть ещё один вариант, улучшенный этот. Но, времени мало, позже, возможно.

Comment: Наверное меня не поняли) Мне нужно скрыть все что вне бордера, белый фон был примером, там ничего нет, просто нужно обрезать все содержимое вне контейнера. А изображение которое внутри него растянуто по странице, но в тоже время, скрыто вне родителя.

Comment: @Predaytor .ib, .il, .ir, .it {
background: white;
}

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе адаптивное решение! Дальше - сами. Мне пора идти. Удачи.

Код:

```css
.m {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
img.f {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* background: yellow; */
    /* opacity: 0; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.it {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(50% - (250px / 2));
    background: blue;
}
.il {
width: calc(54% - (500px / 2));
background: yellow;
}
.i {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: transparent;
border: 12px solid rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.72);
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ir {
width: calc(46% - (500px / 2));
background: yellow;
}
.ib {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #03A9F4;
    height: calc(50% - (250px / 2));
}
.ib, .il, .ir, .it {
    background: rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.63);
}
```

```html
<div class="m">
<img class="f" src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="" >
<div class="c">
<div class="it"></div>
<div class="il"></div><div class="i"></div><div class="ir"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Держите. С вас как можно больше плюсов - минимум. И поддержка)

```css
wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
    /* position: static; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
    /* height: 250px; */
    /* width: 500px; */
    /* float: right; */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* left: 0; */
    right: 0;
    /* bottom: 0; */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .inner img {
    width: calc(100vw + 500px);
    margin-left: -100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Эй! за что минус от кого-то?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-100vw + 500px - 2px);
  height: 99.9vh;
}

.inner img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="http://lukedowding.com/wp-content/uploads/BR2049-Wallpaper-Dam.png?x86078" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```